# Using $http.get in ng-repeat causes multiple errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function what returns an array of items by group Id. Here it is:

```
var getChoices = function (groupId) {
    var request = $http.get(_baseUrl + 'choice', { params: { choiceGroupId: groupId } });

    return request.then(function(result) {
        if (resources.ok(result)) {
            return result.data.items;
        }
    }, function(error) {

    });
}
```

It works fine when I bind it to button, but when I try to make ng-repeat over this function results I have multiple errors in browser console.

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="choice in getChoices(choiceGroupId)">
        {{choice}}
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

I've also tries this, but result is the same.

```
<md-list ng-init="choices = {{getChoices(choiceGroupId)}}">
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        {{choice}}
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

I've seen answers to questions like this, but there people suggested to make request in the controller, then fill the array with data, and iterate over array values, but this doesn't suit my case because I need that `choiceGroupId` from the UI side.

It seems like browser tries to evaluate get request on each tick and something like overflow happens. How can I handle this to call 'get' once and then iterate over returned result?

Comment: you should save the choices result in a scope variable like `scope.choices = return result.data.items;` instead of `return result.data.items;` and use ng-repeat like this `ng-repeat="choice in choices"`. In ng-init you just need to call `getChoices(choiceGroupId)` to tigger the ajax request

Comment: Normally, when you want to invoke this type of services, you create a new instance of it. In your case, it would appear that you are invoking every time the same instance. I would try invoking a function that creates a new variable to which you assign the function and then invokes the function. Take into account also the instance of the promise.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've made as @oliv37 said and now it works fine. After that the `choiceGroupId` was `undefined` because it was taken before form was loadded, i suppose. But i've wrapped my function with `$scope.$on('dataLoaded')` and after that everything works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check If your choices variable has duplication of value , If yes than try below code

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
        {{choice}}
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>



var getChoices = function (groupId) {
    var request = $http.get(_baseUrl + 'choice', { params: { choiceGroupId: groupId } });

    return request.then(function(result) {
        if (resources.ok(result)) {
            $scope.choices= result.data.items;
        }
    }, function(error) {

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem was in another thing.